# Change Chart Border color added as Shape object

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the Border Color of a Chart which was added as a shape. I tried using Macro Recorder but the code does not work when added to my own code. It has some issue with the Shape object it is referencing.

Code used to add Chart:

```
Set Cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=, Width:=, Top:=, Height:=).Chart
```

Code recorded by Macro Recorder:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Line 'Line and pattern color
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Weight = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.8000000119
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
End With
```

The code works for Chart1 but fails when I move to Chart2.

Comment: Where is the Chart 2 code? Where does it crash?

Comment: @Ayush are you trying to update multiple charts ?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.
@Shai Rado - Yes, I have 3 charts in a single sheet and I need to apply these formatting changes to all of them.

Comment: @Jivko - The Chart2 code is the same as Chart1 code. It is just that the reference is changed to Chart2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below to loop through all `Shapes`, and if the shape type is `msoChart` then modify the border and fill properties.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FormatMultiCharts()

Dim MyCht       As Shape

For Each MyCht In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If MyCht.Type Like msoChart Then ' check if shape type is chart
        With MyCht.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
            .Weight = 2
        End With

        With MyCht.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.8000000119
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
    End If
Next MyCht

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Bordering chart with black: 1 == Black color

With ActiveChart.ChartArea
  .Border.ColorIndex = 1
End With